# Opencv functions and wide strings

Tags: c++, opencv, widestring

`Opencv` functions like `cv::imread()` take as arguments only `strings`. So, if I write:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("C:\\folder\\image.jpg");
```

everything is fine and it will load the image. But, if the path contains wide characters (for example greek letters):

```
wstring path = L"C:\\folder\\εικονα.jpg";
```

I can't just write:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread( path );
```

I already tried (and obviously failed) this:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread( string(path.begin(), path.end()) );
```

Is there any solution? Or I'll just have to leave `opencv` and use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current answer is ***NO***, as discussed in [*Issue #4292*](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4292) of the official OpenCV repo.

> One possible workaround for now using Boost and a memory mapped file:
>
> ```
> mapped_file map(path(L"filename"), ios::in);
> Mat file(1, numeric_cast<int>(map.size()), CV_8S, const_cast<char*>(map.const_data()), CV_AUTOSTEP);
> Mat image(imdecode(file, 1));
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write/read images to/from wstring paths using std's filestreams and OpenCV's imdecode and imencode.

```
    wstring path = getPath();
    size_t size = getFileSize(path);
    vector<uchar> buffer(size);

    ifstream ifs(path, ios::in | ios::binary);
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer[0]), size);

    Mat image = imdecode(buffer, flags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use std::filesystem from C++17 as a workaround

```
#include <filesystem>
std::filesystem::path path = L"C:\\folder\\εικονα.jpg";
cv::Mat image = cv::imread( path.string() );
```